# Why do my glow squids disappear?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've been having fun building in the 1.17 snapshot 21w08b and I'm making an underwater cave house. I'm trying to add glow squids because they look nice and they seem to (they don't actually) produce light so I don't need to use sea lanterns, glowstone, glow lichen, etc. to light up the water. I used a spawn egg and placed a lot but they all disappeared whilst I was doing some terraforming away from them. I thought it was normal, I went a bit far away, though I was confused why a passive mob would despawn, even if I wasn't too far away. Next, just to be safe, I named the glow squid egg (I just named it "."). After spawning, they stayed a bit but despawned again. At this point, I knew something was not right. I tried again, but knowing they would just despawn, I added glow squid spawners. I waited for a while, just watching them to see if they would despawn or just die for weird some reason. As I watched, I saw them just disappear one at a time, some did right in front of me. The spawners also didn't spawn anything. If it helps, It's at around Y:3 and the cave is in a plains biome. There are some places for them to swim away, but I'm pretty sure they aren't just swimming away because I saw them disappear in front of me multiple times and nothing is coming from the spawners. Hope someone can help or at least say why this is happening. I don't even need a solution, (though that would be great if I could get one!) I'm just curious of why its happening.

UPDATE: i tested the spawners again and they do actually spawn some, its just very slow and only when im right next to it, so, i't doesnt seem like a viable solution

Answer (score 1):

Squids despite being officially classified as "peaceful", operate under different spawn and despawn conditions than typical 'land' peaceful creatures (animals) - they actually share mob cap with dolphins ("Water creature"), and they definitely can despawn with player far enough.

You'll have to nametag your squids to prevent them from despawning.

Comment: I did name them, unless it only works if you use a nametag specifically and not just name the spawn egg.

Comment: I forgot to mention this in the previous reply, but, even if they can despawn, why do they despawn right next to me / in front of me? I thought if you were close to any mob they wont despawn

Answer (score 0):

You can use commands to make glow squid named if you cheat on you can use
`/summon glow_squid {CustomName:'{"BOB"}'}` witch will name it bob.

Alternatively, you can still use cheats and use `/summon glow_squid {PersistenceRequired:1}` (Not tested) Witch makes it so that it can't despawn.

If you can't use cheats then you will have to name each of them manualy

Comment: Thanks, but the first one didn't even seem to name them (unless its invisible names??) and the second didn't work.
( i tested it by summoning a few then flying really high. each time i couldnt find them anymore)

Comment: @thimothy The firs tone should be `{CustomName: "BOB"}` I think.

Answer (score 0):

**This is simply a glitch in the game.** The glow squids shouldn’t be despawning, as you have named then. Because you are using snapshots such as 21w08b, many early aspects of the new game features are glitches out and don’t appear to be operating properly. This issue has been *reported multiple times* to Mojang [here](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-212325) and the glitch has apparently been fixed in version 21w10a. Hope this helped.

Comment: If you are going to downvote, please explain why. It helps me learn.